# How to increase speed of USB transfers using usb_storage driver/module

Tags: drivers, usb, hard-drive, storage

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with the 5.4.0-42 generic kernel.

I have a WD Elements 25 2TB external USB 3.0 drive attached to a USB 3.0 port at the rear of the computer (not the front panel 3.0 port). For the partition being used for file copying, the system Disks benchmark tools report read speeds of ~95 MB/sec with write speeds of ~120 MB/sec. The sample file size is 50MB. These results are in line with the drive's advertised speeds.

However, I am copying ~70 GB of audio files from this drive to my Android Pixel 2 phone, and the transfer speeds are in the area of <1 MB/sec to ~10 MB/sec. The transfer speed is usually higher at start, in the range of 20MB/sec, but after a while the speed generally drops to ~1 MB/sec.

I understand that transfer cable quality makes a difference, but since I can get 20MB/sec speeds at start, why is that speed unsustainable? Is there any way to significantly increase the transfer speed?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Is your Pixel plugged into a USB 3 port, and is it a USB 3 device? Does your computer also have USB 2 ports? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema The free -h command returns:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.1G        3.4G         18M         10G         13G. The sysctl vm.swappiness command returns: vm.swappiness = 60.
Swap:           14G         73M         14G

Comment: @heynnema: I apologize for the incorrect formatting of the terminal outputs in my response. I could not figure out how to format the code so it would be readable.

Comment: And I also forgot to add that the Pixel 2 XL is a USB 3.0 device and is plugged into a USB 3.0 port attached to the motherboard, not to one of the computer's front panel USB 3.0 ports. The cable was advertised as 3.0 capable.The computer also has USB 2.0 ports. Since I have experienced speeds of nearly 20 MB/sec recently, I am wondering why the transfer slows to about 2MB/sec after a few minutes.

Comment: USB 3.0 cables have blue connectors in each end of the cable. The USB 3.0 ports on the front panel, and the USB 3.0 ports on the motherboard, probably all come directly off of the motherboard. The `free -h` looks ok. Try connecting the Pixel to a USB 2.0 port, and see if things speed up a bit. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema After changing the swappiness setting in my /etc/sysctl.conf file to vm.swappiness=10, I copied some files from the external USB drive to my SSD and tried the file transfer again, from the SSD to the phone, using a USB 2.0 port. The speed started at about 3.2 MB/sec. and was down to 1.6 MB/sec after a few minutes, which seems to eliminate the external drive as the bottleneck. BTW, the Pixel 2 has a USB-C charging/data transfer port and apparently is capable of USB 3.1. I'm starting to think that the issue actually lies with Google's 3.0 implementation. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Are you using `Files` (Nautilus) to copy files? Try using a different file manager and see if things improve. You could also eliminate the Pixel as the bottleneck by connecting a second HDD/SDD instead of the Pixel, and see if file copy speeds improve.

Comment: @heynnma I tried transferring the files to the Pixel using Caja, and the speed was almost 30 MB/sec. Then, using Nautilus I copied the files from the external USB drive to my internal WD hybrid SATA drive. The transfer speed was ~ 40 MB/sec. Seems like copying without using the Nautilus to Pixel 2 combination would be the way to go.

Comment: @heynnema Your responses were helpful. I'd like to accept your answer, but in my browser (Firefox 79.0) there are only flags next to each answer.

Comment: My answer is shown below, and the checkmark is just to the left of my answer. The above items are just comments, and they don't have a checkmark next to them.

Comment: @hyennema I purchased a new Anker 3.0 USB cable and tried the 70 GB transfer using Nautilus. Now the speed is a sustained 24-27 MB/sec. It seems the bottleneck was the off-brand USB cable I had been using.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

re: *I am copying ~70 GB of audio files from this drive (WD Elements 25 2TB external USB 3.0) to my Android Pixel 2 phone, and the transfer speeds are in the area of <1 MB/sec to ~10 MB/sec.*

Try using a different file manager than Nautilus, when copying files to the Pixel 2.

*I tried transferring the files to the Pixel using Caja, and the speed was almost 30 MB/sec.*

**Update #1:**

*I purchased a new Anker 3.0 USB cable and tried the 70 GB transfer using Nautilus. Now the speed is a sustained 24-27 MB/sec. It seems the bottleneck was the off-brand USB cable I had been using.*